# Making one css class be dominant over the other

Tags: css

I have one element which is styled by two css documents:

1.

```
ul[editable="yes"] li {
  background:black;
}
```

2.

```
#menu li {
  background:white;
}
```

As you might have guessed the element I am styling is an LI which is located in the #menu element.

How can i make the "ul[editable="yes"] li" be dominant over "#menu li"?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am presuming that #menu wont be the id of ul to whose li child you are trying to target in first case. (Because IDs are unique and if you are giving same ID to different ul, you are doing it wrong).

The solution would be

```
#menu ul[editable="yes"] li {
  background:black;
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to say for example:
    ul[editable="yes"] li !important {
      background:black;
    }

That would be a lot handier :)

Answer (score 3):

```
background:black !IMPORTANT;
```

You can read more about `!IMPORTANT` here : http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules

Comment: Yeah i know this, I just gave a cut-down example. I want much more styles to be dominant and I don't want to make all of em !important.